# Vertex shader does not apply second attribute array

Tags: android, opengl-es

Consider a simple game with two classes of objects (ball and wall). Tutorials I've found suggests using a single vertex data array in the manner like:

[... initializing ...]

```
vdata = new float[ENOUGH_FOR_ALL];
vertexData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
aPositionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(programId, "a_Position");
glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexData);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
```

[...drawing...]

```
vertexData.position(0);
vertexData.put(vdata);
glUniform4f(uColorLocation, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // ball is red
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, BALL_VERTICES + 2);
glUniform4f(uColorLocation, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // wall is green
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, BALL_VERTICES + 2, 2); // wall as a single line
```

and, the vertex shader is trivial:

```
attribute vec4 a_Position;

void main() {
    gl_Position = a_Position;
}
```

This works but requires cumbersome calculation of offsets in a single buffer, moving when some object size changes...

Consider the following vertex shader

```
attribute vec4 a_Ball;
attribute vec4 a_Wall;
uniform float u_WhatDraw;

void main() {
    if (u_WhatDraw == 1.0) {
        gl_Position = a_Ball;
    }
    else if (u_WhatDraw == 2.0) {
        gl_Position = a_Wall;
    }
}
```

data prepared as:

```
ball_data = new float[BALL_VERTICES + 2];
wall_data = new float[4]; // a single line
ballVertexData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ball_data.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
wallVertexData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(wall_data.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
aBallLocation = glGetAttribLocation(programId, "a_Ball");
glVertexAttribPointer(aBallLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, ballVertexData);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(aBallLocation);
aWallLocation = glGetAttribLocation(programId, "a_Wall");
glVertexAttribPointer(aWallLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, wallVertexData);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(aWallLocation);
```

[...generation of static wall_data skipped...]

[...drawing...]

```
ballVertexData.position(0);
ballVertexData.put(ball_data);
glUniform4f(uColorLocation, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // ball is red
glUniform1f(uWhatDrawLocation, 1.0f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, BALL_VERTICES + 2);
glUniform4f(uColorLocation, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // wall is green
glUniform1f(uWhatDrawLocation, 2.0f);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2); // wall as a single line
```

This does not draw wall at all, despite the ball is drawn.

Please suggest in fixing this with 2-array approach or explain a limitation why I should stick with a single array for all activity.

Answer (score 1):

> This works but requires cumbersome calculation of offsets in a single buffer, moving when some object size changes...

If object size changes you need to reupload new mesh data, so computing offsets seems to be the least of the problems.

> or explain a limitation why I should stick with a single array for all activity.

What happens when you add a third object, or a fourth, or a fifth?

You're optimizing the wrong problem.

Any time you are required to generate shaders with `if (<insert uniform>) ...`  you're doing it wrong - never make the GPU make control plane decisions for every vertex when the application can just do it once.